# https on apache2. https does not work out side home network

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, port, forwarding

I have a personal website running on apache2 on my raspberry pi(raspbian) with no-ip dynamic dns service. Port 80 is forwarded on my home router and the website is accessible outside home network.
Now I am trying to enable https for the website. I have placed the certs on the server,
I ran below first,

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf has,

```
<VirtualHost <my local ip>:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName raspiabita.ddns.net
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf has below

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
      Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
      Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I have forwarded port 443 on my router.
Inside home network, http:// works fine. https:// works fine.
Outside home network, http://raspiabita.ddns.net works. But https://raspiabita.ddns.net does not work. Can any one help me ?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Did you accept the self signed certificate?

Comment: what does that mean? I am able to browse https://localip inside my home network fine. Only outside home network i have issue.

Comment: Browsers will sometimes automatically accept self signed certificates from local domains. It won't accept self signed certs from a remote domain automatically.

Comment: I am trying to access the website from my smartphone which is outside network.By the way my cert is not self signed but issued from certificate authority "Lest Encrypt"